# how to test local language(other than english like chinese, hindi etc) suport by gcc compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, localization

I want to build an library for local language so that i want to know in detail about gcc local language support and as well to update it or to install the new packages for local language support.

Comment: Have you looked at a standard framework like [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The [localization or internationalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) is not the job of the compiler (unless you are talking about getting compiler diagnostic message in Chinese or French, which `gcc` does already).

However, the standard way in C of localizing output is to use the standard libc framework, e.g. [setlocale(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) (see also [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) ....), and [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) with [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), etc... (Please follow that link to [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)). You'll probably also use [gettextize](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/gettextize-Invocation.html) etc.. See also wikipage on [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) ...

You would probably then use e.g. `printf(gettext("some message with number %d"), i);`. Many software use that so often that they define a macro

```
#define _(Msg) gettext(Msg)
```

and code `printf(_("some message with number %d"), i);`

Some toolkits also provide their internationalization or localization framework, e.g. [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/internationalization.html).

<sup>PS. Your question is probably operating system specific. I am focusing on Posix and Linux in my answer (I have no idea what Windows is and does).</sup>